# R mutate produces error 'Must be size 1, not 10'

Tags: r, mutate

Here is my df

| Airline | Destination | delayed | ontime | Total_Arrivals |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Alaska | Los Angelos | 62 | 497 | 559 |
| Alaska | Phoenix | 12 | 221 | 233 |
| Alaska | San Diego | 20 | 212 | 232 |
| Alaska | San Francisco | 102 | 503 | 605 |
| Alaska | Seatlle | 305 | 1841 | 2146 |
| AM West | Los Angelos | 117 | 694 | 811 |
| AM West | Phoenix | 415 | 4840 | 5255 |
| AM West | San Diego | 65 | 383 | 448 |
| AM West | San Francisco | 129 | 320 | 449 |
| AM West | Seatlle | 61 | 201 | 262 |

I am trying to use the below to calculate percentage:

```
     Airline_Arrivals_Long_Test <-Airline_Arrivals_Wide %>%
         mutate(Airline_Arrivals_Wide, (delayed/Total_Arrivals)*100)
```

But i get the following error:

Error in `mutate()`:
ℹ In argument: `Airline_Arrivals_Wide`.
ℹ In row 1.
Caused by error:
! `Airline_Arrivals_Wide` must be size 1, not 10.
ℹ Did you mean:  `= list(Airline_Arrivals_Wide)` ?
Backtrace:

1. Airline_Arrivals_Wide %>% ...
2. dplyr:::dplyr_internal_error(...)

What is the issue here?
I am supposed to calculate in dplyr

Comment: It should be: `Airline_Arrivals_Wide %>% mutate((delayed/Total_Arrivals)*100)`.  When using the pipe operator `%>%` drop the reference to the data frame.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You must remove the second argument (Airline_Arrivals_Wide) and  create a new column **'percentage'** using the delayed and Total_Arrivals columns:

```
Airline_Arrivals_Long_Test <- Airline_Arrivals_Wide %>%
  mutate(percentage = (delayed/Total_Arrivals)*100)
```